# Is there a way to get a random value from a Python dictionary and find a value from another dictionary using it?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm trying to make a system where I take a value from a dictionary, and then attempt to find a value from a different dictionary with it. I've attempted this multiple times and have not been successful.

```
import random

dic = {
        '1': 'hi',
        '2': 'hi2',
    }
dic2 = {
        '1': 'hello',
        '2': 'hello2',
}

x = random.choice(list(dic))
print(x)
y = dic2['x']
print(y)
```

This code is non-funcitonal and returns `File "<PATH>", line 16, in <module> <y = dic2['x'] KeyError: 'x'`

Comment: `dic2[random.choice(list(dic.keys()))]`  This would work, but as for your bug, one problem is that `x` is a variable, and in your second to last line you have it surrounded by quotes, making it a string.  Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close!

```
import random

dic = {
        '1': 'hi',
        '2': 'hi2',
    }
dic2 = {
        '1': 'hello',
        '2': 'hello2',
}

x = random.choice(list(dic.keys()))
print(x)
y = dic2[x]
print(y)
```

Here I took a random value from the keys of the dictionary.
And then I had to remove the annotation characters because this way x is a variable and not a string

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Remove the single quotes around the x in the line:

```
y = dic2[x]
```

Look at it this way: you mean: Whatever is in the variable you named x. Not whatever is labeled with the character "x". You can remove the quotes in the dict declaration too if you want. Where your code says: I want an item "Hi" with the name "1" (the letter one - so to speak), this code

```
1: 'hi',
```

would mean: I want the word "Hi" to be in an item labeled with the actual number 1 as its key.